# Jersey @ManagedAsync and copying data between HTTP thread and Worker thread

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, jersey, servlet-3.0

I am working on a project that works in two flavors with and without multi tenancy.

The project exposes a REST service which I would like to be asynchronous.
So my basic service looks like

```
@Component
@Path("/resouce")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ResouceEndpoint {
    @POST
    @ManagedAsync
    public void add(final Event event, @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        resouce.insert (event);
        asyncResponse.resume( Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT).build());     
    }
}
```

That works fine without multi tenancy and I get the benefits of the internal Jersey executor service for free. See [@ManagedAsync](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ManagedAsync.html)

When I switch to multi tenancy I add a filter on the request that resolve the tenant id and place it on the thread local (in our case the HTTP thread).

When the processing chain hits the "add()" method above the current thread is the one provided by the Jersey executor service, so it does not include my tenant id.
I could think only on the following options to work around this issue.

Extend the  ResouceEndpoint to MutliTenantResouceEndpoint and drop the @ManagedAsync
Using my own thread executor

```
public class MutliTenantResouceEndpoint extends ResouceEndpoint {
    @POST
    public void add(final Event event, @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        final String tenantId = getTeantIdFromThreadLocal();
        taskExecutor.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                setTeantIdToThreadLocal(tenantId);
                browserEventsAnalyzer.insertEvent(event);
                Response response = Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT).build();
                asyncResponse.resume(response);
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But this way I need to manage my own thread executor and it feel's like I am missing something here.
Any suggestion on a different approach?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here are a handful of recommendations, in order.

For context, I've been using Jersey for 2 years, and faced this exact problem 18 months ago.

### 1. Stop using `@ManagedAsync`

If you have control over the http server that Jersey is running on, I would recommend you stop using `@ManagedAsync`.

Instead of setting up Jersey to return it's http handling thread immediately and offload real request work to a managed executor service thread, use something like [Grizzly](https://grizzly.java.net/) for your http server, and configure it to have a larger worker thread pool. This accomplishes the same thing, but pushes the async responsibility down a layer, below Jersey.

You'll run into many pain points over the course of a year if you use `@ManagedAsync` for any medium-to-large project. Here are some of them off the top of my head:

- If any ContainerRequestFilter's hits an external service (e.g. an auth filter hits your security module, which hits the database) you will lose the benefits you thought you were gaining

  - If your DB chokes and that auth filter call takes 5 seconds, Jersey hasn't offloaded work to the async thread yet, so your main thread needed to receive a new conn is blocked
- If you set up logback's MDC in a filter, and you want that context throughout your request, you'll need to set up the MDC again on the managed async thread
- Resource methods are cryptic to new comers and ugly to read because:

  - they need an extra parameter
  - they return void, hiding their real response type
  - they can "return" anywhere, without any actual `return` statements
- Swagger or other API doc tools cannot automatically document async resource endpoints
- Guice or other DI frameworks may have trouble dealing with certain scope bindings and/or providers in async resource endpoints

### 2. Use `@Context` and `ContainerRequest` properties

This would involve involved calling `requestContext.setProperty("tenant_id", tenantId)` in your filter, then calling calling `requestContext.getProperty("tenant_id")` in your resource with a `@Context` injected request.

### 3. Use HK2 AOP instead of Jersey filters

This would involve setting up an HK2 binding of `InterceptionService` which has a `MethodInterceptor` that checks for managed async resource methods and manually executes all `RequestScoped` bound `ContainerRequestFilter`s. Instead of your filters being registered with Jersey, you'd register them with HK2, to be run by the method interceptor.

I can add more detail and code samples to options 2/3 if you'd like, or give additional suggestions, but it would first be helpful to see more of your filter code, and I again suggest option 1 if possible.

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer
I eventually used option 1 suggested. I will try option 3 when I will have time and let you know. Option 2 is irrelevant since I have to used the filter  as is.

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but still. Do you have any examples suggestions on how
To tackle the MDC pitfall you mentioned? 

Would setting a custom Executor + AsyncExecutor that simple copies contexts
suffice?